# Run multiple independent void functions using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspbian

How to run multiple (say 6) independent functions using python's multiprocessing?
I've been searching for relevant examples, but I couldn't find any single example which shows example for functions without arguments. Is there any way to achieve such functionality as illustrated in the attached picture using multiprocessing? I'm looking for an example structure code that I can use and build upon.

[Intended code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65yrY.png)

Edit: Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import obd
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from ctypes import*
from mcp3208 import MCP3208
from mq import MQ
from smokeSensor import smokePercentage
adc = MCP3208()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#------Temperature Sensor Module-----------------------
bmp280_lib = CDLL('/home/pi/OBIBB/TempNew/_bmp280_driver.so')
#bmp280_lib = CDLL('/usr/local/lib/_bmp280_driver.so')
bmp280_lib.bmp280GetTempReadings.restype = c_double
bmp280_lib.DisplayAdds.restype = c_void_p
bmp280_lib.bmp280Setup()
################ OBD initialization #########################
ports = obd.scan_serial()       # return list of valid USB or RF ports
print ports                    # ['/dev/ttyUSB0', '/dev/ttyUSB1']
connection = obd.OBD() # auto-connects to USB or RF port


def Read_RPM:
        RESP_RPM = connection.query(cmdrpm)
        return RESP_RPM.value


#cmdrpm = obd.commands.RPM #  OBD command (for reading speed)
def ReadHumidity (Channel):
        # The read_adc function will get the value of the specified channel (0-7).
        readData = adc.read(Channel)
                v_in= (readData*3.3)/4096
                RH=(((v_in/v_supp)-0.1515)/0.00636)
        # Return the ADC values.
        return RH
#################################################
def READ_SENSORS(return_dict):
        v_in = 0
        RH=0
        v_supp=3.3
        HumdityChannel = 0
        T = bmp280_lib.bmp280GetTempReadings()
        Humd = ReadHumidity (HumdityChannel)
        smok = smokePercentage()
        print T
        print Humd
        print smok

def displayAdds():
        os.system("sh kda-chowrangi.sh")

def runInParallel(*fns):
  proc = []
  for fn in fns:
        p = Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        runInParallel(READ_SENSORS)
        pool = Pool(processes=10)
        pool.map_async(displayAdds)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We will need to see what you have tried first. Could you also please only choose one python version tag.

Comment: @ZackTarr, yes. I've added the code snippet.